# Storing and retrieving default values for fields in a related model instance

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to store default values for a model instance in a related object; for example, given this code:

```
class Contract(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    duration = models.IntegerField(null=True, help_text='Contract validity (days)')
    template = models.ForeignKey(ContractTemplate)

class ContractTemplate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField(help_text='Contract validity (days)')
```

I would like to store objects representing different common durations like:

```
yearly_contract = ContractTemplate.object.create(name='yearly', duration=365)
monthly_contract = ContractTemplate.object.create(name='monthly', duration=30)
```

and return the default value from the linked template when the object contract does not specify the value:

```
contract1 = Contract.objects.create(user=foo_user, foo_product, template=monthly_contract)
# contract1.duration should return 365

contract2 = Contract.objects.create(user=foo_user, foo_product, duration=45, template=monthly_contract)
# contract2.duration should return 45
```

So, what is the best way to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callable object as default. Which seems to be what you want:

Have a look here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: Almost good, but using a default will only apply the value at object creation and I am not sure how can you get the value from the related yearly_contract instance before saving it.

Comment: That will be with your form

Comment: maybe you could access that into the create function of the Contract model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects